# [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, gpt-3

It says [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred. But inreality i am using editReply

I am having issue in logging error, it works fine with try and else but it shows `[InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred` in catch (error). I even tried using followUp  but still doesnt work, it keeps giving the same error and shuts the whole bot down.

```
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("chat-gpt")
  .setDescription("chat-gpt-3")
  .addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName('prompt')
      .setDescription('Ask Anything')
      .setRequired(true)),

  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const prompt = interaction.options.getString('prompt');
    await interaction.deferReply();

    const configuration = new Configuration({
      apiKey: "nvm",
    });
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
    
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt: prompt,
      max_tokens: 2048,
      temperature: 0.7,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0.0,
      presence_penalty: 0.0,
    });

    let responseMessage = response.data.choices[0].text;

    /* Exceed 2000 */

    try {
      let responseMessage = response.data.choices[0].text;
      if (responseMessage.length >= 2000) {
        const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(Buffer.from(responseMessage, 'utf-8'), { name: 'chatgpt-response.txt' });
        const limitexceed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`Reached 2000 characters`)
        .setDescription(`Sorry, but you have already reached the limit of 2000 characters`)
        .setColor(`#FF6961`);
        await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [limitexceed], files: [attachment] });
        
      } else {
        const responded = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`You said: ${prompt}`)
        .setDescription(`\`\`\`${response.data.choices[0].text}\`\`\``)
        .setColor(`#77DD77`);
  
        await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [responded] });   
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      await interaction.followUp({ content: `error` });
    }

    return;
  },
};
```

i even tried using followUp or etc but the result is still same.

Comment: That's not ChatGPT you're talking to, there.

Answer (score 0):

## Your Problem

I believe the error occur in the `catch()` method (Line 55).

Please be reminded that the interaction has been deferred at Line 14:

```js
await interaction.deferReply();
```

## Explanation

Each interaction can only be replied and deferred once only. If you want to make changes on it, consider using the  `editReply()` method.

## Solution

Simply replace the code on Line 55 with editReply and this will solve the current error.

```js
await interaction.editReply({ content: `error` });
```